# Flutter in-app purchase (IAP) Store unavailable

Tags: android, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I  am implementing in-app purchases thanks to the [IAP package](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) but I get the message unable to connect to the payment processor while using Android Emulator.

I used the code in the example.

Apparently

```dart
Future<void> initStoreInfo() async {
    final bool isAvailable = await _connection.isAvailable();
```

is where the problem arose.

I don't know what I missed. I also added

```dart
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

in the file profile/AndroidManifest.xml

How can I make it work?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: add to pay product ? url link : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481?hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make sure that your emulator has the Google play store
   You can check in AVD as below, or simply look for the play store app on the emulator
   You will need play store services to proceed with payments

[image: AVD manager]

2. Check that the `compileSdkVersion` of your app match with the one of the IAP package
   On the [changelog page](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase/changelog) you will see that the `compileSdkVersion` changed to 29 on the 0.3.4+15 version of the package
   You can adjust your version in `android\app\build.gradle`, or use an older version of the package if needed

Comment: Best they should have provided a check list. the ones in the documentation is not complete since i still get that error even if i use the emulator with the play store in it.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the compileSdkVersion of your app match with the one of the IAP package
On the changelog page you will see that the compileSdkVersion changed to 29 on the 0.3.4+15 version of the package
You can adjust your version in android\app\build.gradle, or use an older version of the package if needed

This work for me Thank!.