# Flutter In_App_Purchase Error Store is not available

Tags: flutter, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am using Windows 11 with Android Studio emulator.

I run the exact code shown on this page: pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase/example

I get the error:

[image]

Could you please explain what the error means and what I am doing wrong.

Thank You

Comment: Make sure you're testing on an emulator with the PlayStore support. *** Does this answer your question? [Flutter in-app purchase (IAP) Store unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63184370/flutter-in-app-purchase-iap-store-unavailable)

Comment: For all my Android Emulators, the setting: PlayStore.enabled is false. There is no way to change this setting. If I create a new Emulator, then I don't see any options including advanced settings to enable PlayStore. In the package installation instructions, there is no information about permissions.

Comment: while creating a new emulator, you have to install the one that shows play store icon below the title 'Play Store' as shown in the above comment's link I posted .

Comment: I installed the image Pixel 7 Pro that has Google Play Store, and I still see the same error. Please help. Thank You